# Remotely-Called Process Failing to Update Database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, service, service-reference, autosys

I'm currently working with a process that imports a CSV file into our database, then produces and zips an output flat file that details the entries added that hadn't existed before or were changed.

At the moment, if the process is run in Visual Studio or from the .exe file, everything goes off without a hitch, and we are provided the files and can verify the changes to the database.

If, however, the process is called through Autosys (our workload automation tool), we're given the output file as well as a log file listing the called methods and variable values, but no changes are made to the database.

We've imported both a Service Reference and a Web Reference for this purpose, but while they're very similar, it's only the Service Reference that works for us at all. I'm not entirely certain this particular detail might make a difference, but thought it'd be worth mentioning.

This is an issue I've spent quite a bit of time looking into, applied proxies and attempting to sort through things in Visual Studio, but haven't had any luck at all with. Would anyone happen to have experienced anything similar, or possibly have any insights as to the cause of this that I may have overlooked so far? Right now it just feels like I've been spinning my wheels and getting nowhere for far too long, and I could really use any available assistance and advice I can find.

Comment: I'm assuming Autosys runs on a separate machine. Could it possibly be a firewall issue?

Comment: That's been one of our best guesses, too, but working with the client with this is quite difficult; there are all sorts of security protocols in place that make any kind of dialogue or information exchange incredibly slow-going, which was why I thought I'd check here to see if anyone had similar experiences, while waiting to hear back from them.